# Adapters in your Model-View-ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am doing a school project using WPF and MVVM and I were wondering if it is ok to have an adapter within one of my Models or should I do it in my ViewModel? The Model I am talking about is looking like this:

```
public class P2PMeterSession
{
   public P2PMeterAnnounce MeterAnnounce { get; set; }
   public DateTime DisposeTime { get; set; }
   public DateTime GetMimTime { get; set; }
   public DateTime SetTimeTime { get; set; }
   public DateTime LoadProfileLogHackTime { get; set; }
   public List<DateTime> GetConventionalDataTime { get; set; }
   public DateTime GetGsmDataTime { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<DateTime, SessionEvent> Sessionevents { get; set; }

   public P2PMeterSession()
   {
      GetConventionalDataTime = new List<DateTime>();
   }
   public int GetSessionTimeSpan
   {
      get
      {
         var sessionStart = MeterAnnounce.MeterAnnounceTimeStamp;
         var sessionEnd = DisposeTime;
         return (int)(sessionEnd - sessionStart).TotalSeconds;
      }
    }
    public List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>> ReturnEvents
    {
       get
       {
          List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>> RE = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>>();
          var AnnounceEvent = MeterAnnounce.MeterAnnounceTimeStamp;
          var DisposeEvent = DisposeTime;
          var GetMimEvent = GetMimTime;
          var SetTimeEvent = SetTimeTime;
          var LoadProfileLogHackTimeEvent = LoadProfileLogHackTime;
          var GetConventionalDataEvent = GetConventionalDataTime;
          var GetGsmDataEvent = GetGsmDataTime;

          RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(AnnounceEvent, SessionEvent.Announce));
          if (GetMimTime != DateTime.MinValue)
             RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(GetMimEvent, SessionEvent.GetMim));
          if (SetTimeTime != DateTime.MinValue)
             RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(SetTimeEvent, SessionEvent.SetTime));
          if (LoadProfileLogHackTime != DateTime.MinValue)
             RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(LoadProfileLogHackTimeEvent, SessionEvent.LoadProfileLogHack));
          if (GetConventionalDataTime != null)
             GetConventionalDataTime.ForEach(x => RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(x, SessionEvent.GetConventionalData)));
          if (GetGsmDataTime != DateTime.MinValue)
             RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(GetGsmDataEvent, SessionEvent.GetGsmData));

           RE.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, SessionEvent>(DisposeEvent, SessionEvent.Dispose));
           return RE;
        }
    }

    public enum SessionEvent 
    { 
       Announce, 
       Dispose, 
       GetMim, 
       SetTime, 
       LoadProfileLogHack, 
       GetConventionalData, 
       GetGsmData
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at TDD and use an interface for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using MVVM in general, view models should provide *all relevant data and functionality* to their related views. Therefore, any data access services, or *adapters* as you call them should be accessible from the view models rather than the model classes, so that they can access the data and display it in the views.

While some may disagree with this, I tend to use model, or data type, classes as just 'containers' for data and prefer to expose any functionality in the view models. This enables me to test that functionality along with the other view model tests as standard.

As your project is just a school project, it is unlikely that you will be writing unit tests for your view models. However, if you are, then your *adapter* may interfere with the tests. If any code in there needs to be tested separately, you can create an interface from your `P2PMeterSession` class and add a property of type `IP2PMeterSession` into the view model.

Populate this property with an actual instance of `P2PMeterSession` when running the application and with a `MockP2PMeterSession` class during testing. The `MockP2PMeterSession` class can just return preset data, or even nothing depending on your tests.